# native gwt charts library

Tags: gwt, charts, gchart

Are there any native gwt chart libraries that work offline and open sourced?

Answer (score 2):

GXT charts are either commercially licensed or GPLv3, are maintained, good looking (at least I think so), and run in the browser entirely. They support SVG/VML to support all major browsers, and as of GXT 3.1 can render in canvas as well.

Comment: they are not native GWT, and I've read many reviews that say at a certain step GXT charts become a bottelneck of big applications

Comment: GXT is absolutely native GWT, and I can say so having worked on it for several years. The *only* JSNI present in the GXT charts are for dealing with SVG specifics of text rendering or getting around different browser quirks, but 100% of the charts are in Java, and the draw engine it builds on is specific to the platform you compile for. The rest of GXT has slightly more JSNI, mostly involved with providing a fast DOM query engine, faster than what we've been able to find in the rest of the GWT world.

Comment: Colin, thank you for your feedback. I had a bad experience with smartGWT, and Sencha seems to have similar problems (they don't support some basic grid / chart features, like export to excel. And its not trivial to extend them). Am I wrong?

Comment: SmartGWT is a wrapped library, unlike GXT, which is all native GWT/Java. Export to excel is tricky, or we would have done it - the big part is that end users want to pass down data to the _browser_ and expect it to push it into a csv/whatever file. Instead, that is really the server's problem, since you might have the grid configured for paging/filtering/sorting, and the export probably shouldn't just be the 20 items that are visible (and the browser knows), but the entire 20,000 item list...

Comment: Extending for look and feel isn't too bad, adding new UI features is designed to be pretty easy, but for server side tasks, GXT really assumes that the server side is responsible. Check out any of the many great libraries that can live on the server to export data in different formats.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [gwt-visualization](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/downloads/detail?name=gwt-visualization-1.1.2.zip&) library. It's also not actively maintained, but it does almost everything out of the box, and you can always extend a few classes to add the latest features from Google Charts API.

Comment: thanks Andrei. Isn't gwt-visualization require an internet connection: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/faq?csw=1#offline ? That seems like a problem, because most of our clients have intranet connections only

Comment: Yes, it needs to connect to Google's servers. Sorry, I missed your "offline" requirement.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/gwt-charts/  - the unofficial gwt-visualization looks that it works better than the official one, but still it does not have the "offline" requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I am using and developing [Charba](https://github.com/pepstock-org/Charba) library. It's actively maintained and it's a wrapper of [Chart.JS](https://www.chartjs.org/).